# Unable to create desired url in cakephp2

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.4, cakephp-2.5

I started learning cakephp2 and was following the basic tutorial. But I find most of the tutorials out there complicated and hard to understand. I want to a make a simple site that allows the user to transition to the item page from shop list page. I want the url to display like (sample.com/shoplist/items).maybe I'm having trouble with Controller. It would be great help if a simple there are some simple sample. I would love to hear from you.

Comment: first you should start from [Blog Tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the usual use of the framework, you have: `domain/controller/action` as the URL. CakePHP will look for a `View` file with the same name as the `action` to show on the window.

So, one way to accomplish what you've discussed, would be to have a `controller` named `ShoplistController.php` where you can have `index`as the action for the main View, which should be called `index.ctp`.

Then, when the user wants to look at items, these could happen with an action called `items`, which would demand the View file `items.ctp`.

However, it's important to note that while working with CakePHP (And other MVC frameworks), it's best to organize Models, Controllers, and Views based on their actual jobs and responsibilities, not the URL they build.

It's also important to note that the suggestions I'm providing here assume everything is in the right place: `Controller` file in the `app/Controller` directory and `Views` in the `app/View/Shoplist` directory.

Comment: Agreed. Once you have your Models and Controllers, you can always use the Router (Config/routes.php) to define alternative URLs to get to the page you want.